# How to transfrom/translate text element in d3?

Tags: d3.js, svg, transform, translate

I'm trying to translate my svg text (axis label) in order I can center it with svg container. I've tried with this code:

```
svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y",100)
  .attr("transform", "translate(-50%, -50%)")
  .text("any text");
```

Moreover nothing happens. Other svg elements are translated with no problems, but, The text doesn't move from its original position. What is wrong, whats is the correct way to translate svg text?

Comment: Can you share the detailed code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `%` signs from the arguments you pass to `translate`:

```
svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y", 100)
  .attr("transform", "translate(-50, -50)")
  .text("any text");
```

You can check the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Translate).

Comment: Thanks @edgar-r-mondragón it works without % sign. So it is not possible to do it with percentages?

Comment: According to the docs it's not possible. The comma is optional though. If the answer was helpful, consider marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

> D3 Version 6 - Working Example with  element

```
const fontSize = 1.714em;

innerCircleText.append('text')
.attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
.style('font-size', `${fontSize}em`)
.style('transform', `translate(0, ${0.5 / fontSize}em)`)
.text('24')
```

This was used to slightly move the text closer to center as the size of the font moved around a bit from middle.

Note: If I leave off the "em" in this
.style('transform', `translate(0, ${0.5 / fontSize}em)`)

The browser will not use it. Yet if I leave it on, and 0 has no metric, this is what shows up in browser...
transform: translate(0px, 0.291715em)

with the transform working...